# Selecting the 2nd word in a hashset and converting it to a String? Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, hashmap, hashset

I'm making a text based RPG where I want to implement a universal command "use" which will activate the effect of an item (equip weapons / drink potions / launch fireworks). All these things are ready at a methods notice.  However i need to select that specific item by a String through a HashSet without using .contains.

This is my InputReader class

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputReader
{
    private Scanner reader;

    /**
     * Create a new InputReader that reads text from the text terminal.
     */
    public InputReader()
    {
        reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    /**
     * Read a line of text from standard input (the text terminal),
     * and return it as a set of words.
     *
     * @return  A set of Strings, where each String is one of the
     *          words typed by the user
     */
    public HashSet<String> getInput()
    {
        System.out.print("> ");                // print prompt
        String inputLine = reader.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();

        String[] wordArray = inputLine.split(" ");  // split at spaces

        // add words from array into hashset
        HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
        for(String word : wordArray) {
            words.add(word);
        }
        return words;
    }
}
```

And this is my method for starting the rpg.

```
public void startBattle() {
        printWelcomeMessage();
        boolean finished = false;

        while(!finished && monsters.size() > 0) {
        HashSet<String> commands = reader.getInput();

        if(commands.contains("use"))
         {
// Use an item by name after the word "use" else print "didn't specify item"
         }
```

I have tried alot of methods being streams (which i don't know how to use) to different formats of ArrayLists.  How could I simply take all these words, stick them into an ArrayList, and just iterate through them checking for items I might have using this method in my Player class (also stopping if it finds an item, I don't want it to use every single item it finds in the string at once):

```
public Item findItem(String search) {
        return this.items.get(search);
    }
```

Items is the inventory of the player in a HashMap format

Comment: `ArrayList.indexOf()`?...or `HashMap`?

Comment: Why use the hashset at all?  This would be simple if you just left the commands as an array.  Then you can go through the words in the array, in order one by one.  Hashset just seems to be making things more complicated here for no benefit that I can see.

Comment: `HashSet` is not ordered. There is no "second word".

Comment: Where would i use this?

Comment: I'd have to rewrite a new inputreader then.  I didn't write this one, and I'm not familiar with the terms @shmosel

Comment: Yes, you probably would.

Comment: @shmosel Also it doesn't technically have to be the 2nd word, i just need a way to iterate every word through the findItem method, so that I can run the useItem method within the item it selects

Comment: @Peebl `indexOf()`...

Comment: If you change `HashSet` to an `ArrayList` you can do something like this `return commands.get(commands.indexOf("use")+1)` Just make sure that  `commands.indexOf("use")+1 < commands.size() - 1` and `commands.indexOf("use") != -1`;

Comment: Could you give some sample user inputs? Are `use sword` and `I want to use my sword` both valid ones?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned: Get rid of the HashSet. It wouldn't help you. As shomsel pointed out already, the fact that a Set is not ordered makes it a bad choice for your problem.

Every input you receive is made up of a stream of characters. These characters form tokens - For example you are using the space as a delimiter, which just is a cartein token in your stream. These tokens are the words of the language - You're indeed dealing with a language here - you want to build.

So first you'll need a tokenizer: A bit of software wich transforms the stream of characters into a stream of tokens. You've already implemented the handling of the delimiter token:

```
String[] wordArray = inputLine.split(" ");  // split at spaces
```

Now you have to implement the parsing of your tokens stored in the String-Array. This is a more difficult part.

You've to iterate over the words and decide, if this word is used in the right context within your token stream. Simply put: You'll need some kind of syntax check.

After you're sure that you've recieved a syntactically correct stream of tokens/words you have to build - For example - a decision tree to execute the desired action described by the token stream. I guess this will be the most difficult part.

I suggest that you take a look at Antlr: http://www.antlr.org/

It's a tool to build lexers/parsers and could be ao good use for ue regarding this problem.

Best regards

Alex

Comment: I think Antlr would be a bit of a stretch at this point for OP.

Comment: @biziclop: Yeah, you're most probably right. It would be like using a battleship's cannon to kill a mosquito.
Another approach could be to build classes of the vocabulary and write a simple check to see if the received sentence is syntactically and semantically correct in the context of the problem.

Comment: Oh, before I forget it: A little input sanitizing would be probably a good idea: Condense all whitespaces to one space - a regex replace should do the trick - before splitting the input.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the fact that using HashSet in your case is simply wrong, because it doesn't preserve order.
Simple example:

```
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

    set.add("use");
    set.add("zebra");

    System.out.println(set);
    // [zebra, use]
```

Which is clearly not what you want.

I would suggest using a Queue:

```
    Queue<String> words = new LinkedList<>();

    words.add("some");
    words.add("junk");
    words.add("use");
    words.add("zebra");
    words.add("Run");
    words.add("away");


    while(!words.isEmpty()) {

        String word = words.poll();

        if ("use".equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
            String subject = words.poll();

            System.out.println(String.format("Using %s", subject));
            break; //This will leave your current loop
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Left to do " + words.toString());
```